# android text of all TextViews with same id is changed between onStart and onResume

Tags: android

I am implementing a view showing a list of items, allowing the user to sort them by drag and drop. This worked fine until I tried to rotate the screen. Then the text of all items is changed to the text of the last item between onStart and onResume (or in super.onResume).

I have simplified the code to the following, still producing this strange behaviour:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout root;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.out.println(" ### on create ### ");
        if (root!=null) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.println(" !!! root is null !!!");
        root = new LinearLayout(this);
        root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        for (int id=0; id<6; id++) {
            View out = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) out.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text);
            //TextView tv = (TextView) ((LinearLayout)out).getChildAt(1); // for this special list_item layout this line is equivalent to the above
            tv.setText("test item "+id);
            System.out.println(tv.getText());
            root.addView(out);
        }

        setContentView(root);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        System.out.println("on start");
        System.out.println(((TextView) root.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.list_item_text)).getText());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        System.out.println("on resume");
        System.out.println(((TextView) root.getChildAt(1).findViewById(R.id.list_item_text)).getText());
    }

}
```

layout/list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/list_item_knob"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:background="#FFD0A0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_text" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

While trying around I have found out that when removing the id of the TextView in the xml layout file the text is not changed anymore (this requires of course finding another way to get the TextView in the java code). Then it works but this is not acceptable because I want to be able to use arbitrary xml layouts where the TextView need not be child 1 of a LinearLayout.

The log shows that the change of the text is happening between onStart and onResume (or in super.onResume). Also the attribute root is always null when onCreate is called after rotating the screen.

Why does the text of all TextViews with the same id change when rotating the screen? And why does it not when launching the app for the first time?

How do I avoid that the text is changing automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point is - any activity is recreated each time user rotates the device. So, you should handle the recreation process properly. There is a method [onSaveInstanceState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) of `Activity`, in the method you can store any values that matters in the `Bundle` and later use in `onCreate` method(as there is a parameter of Bundle type).

Here is a small example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView test1;
private TextView test2;

private final String KEY_1 = "key_1";
private final String KEY_2 = "key_2";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    test1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test1);
    test2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test2);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_1)) {
            test1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_1));
        }
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_2)) {
            test2.setText(savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_2));
        }
    }

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                test1.append("1");
            } else {
                test2.append("2");
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(KEY_1, test1.getText().toString());
    outState.putString(KEY_2, test2.getText().toString());
}
}
```

And the XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text1" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/test2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text2" >
</TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: that explains why root is null. However I do not see how saving the text of the views in onSaveInstanceState and applying them in onCreate is supposed to help me, because the problem is that the text in the views is overwritten after onCreate.

Comment: @jakun you have to repopulate view container using the data stored in the Bundle, may be you should empty it first. So, if the `Bundle` is not null and contain text data - use it to recreate TextViews with the state they had before rotation. Otherwise populate the view like it is the first start of the application.

Comment: I have added a `if (savedInstanceState!=null) savedInstanceState.clear();` directly after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and that has really solved it. Thank you so much! Later on this list will be populated based on a database.